# Mapping an History Object to a Project Object with JPA persistence

Tags: java, database, jpa, annotations

Here's a minimal-example database of my program :

[image: database]

I try to map these tables to the following Java Classes using JPA annotations (I'm quite new with those Gremlins)

---

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    String project_name;

    @Column
    String description;

    @ ??
    History history;


    // methods
    ...
}
```

**History.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "histories")
public class History {

    @Id
    String history_id;

    @ ??
    Map<Date, String> sets; // represents the date/description pairs associated to the project


    // methods
    ...
}
```

The mapping seems to be a bit hard challenge, It's not homework, I just wonder if this is good practice. Does my classes' layout need to look alike with the database structure ?
Ideally I wish my objects' logic is bound to my project's specification, I also wish freezing my objects' structure to one paradigm doesn't have an influence on the database organisation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in java objects you should stick to java naming conventions. For example, `project_name` DB column should be mapped to `projectName` field (using `@Column` annotation). Second, it is not 100% clear from DB diagram what is the relation between those two tables, but judging from a name in plural (`histories`) I'll guess it is `@OneToMany`. Third, that Map in History entity (`sets`) can't be done like that, but it is covered with `@OneToMany` relation. Try something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "project_name")
    private String projectName;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<History> historyList;

    // getters and setters
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "histories")
public class History {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "history_id")
    private Integer historyId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) // or TemporalType.TIMESTAMP
    private Date date;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_name")
    private Project project;

    // getters and setters
    ...
}
```